# while executing the function frame2im(F)

Tags: matlab, video

I am repeatedly getting error report in MATLAB that says:

> Invalid input argument type to 'set'.
>   Type 'help set' for options.

When i tried for the options, i don't find any solution regarding error message.

Here is my code:

```
framedata = mmreader('filename.avi',1);
I1=frame2im(framedata);
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: According to the docs (for R2011b), the `mmreader` syntax is `mmreader(filename)` or `mmreader(filename, propertyname, propertyvalue)` - your code doesn't match either of the two. If your `1` value is supposed to set a certain property, you'll have to provide that property-name as well.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the newer and better `VideoReader` instead? I believe that it exists in 2011b.

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs (for R2011b), the mmreader syntax is `mmreader(filename)` or `mmreader(filename, propertyname, propertyvalue, ...)`.

Your code doesn't match either of the two. If your `1` value is supposed to set a certain property, you'll have to provide that property-name as well.

Also, `mmreader` constructs an object and does not immediately return framedata.
So you should check the remaining parts of your code as well.